# Create an instance from serializer without persisting it to db

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Working in the context of [creating a django model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects):

```
# Creates potato and saves a row to db
spud = Potato.objects.create(...)

# Also creates a potato instance, but doesn't hit db yet.
# Could call `spud.save()` later if/when we want that.
spud = Potato(...)
```

In [factory boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#using-factories) we also have an analogy for this Djangoism

```
# Returns a saved instance
spud = PotatoFactory.create()

# Returns an instance that's not saved
spud = PotatoFactory.build()
```

In [rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) v3.3.2, I can't find the analogy.  Is it possible?

```
serializer = PotatoSerializer(data=...)

# creates the instance and saves in db
serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
```

I can write my own, something like this:

```
class PotatoSerializer:
    ...
    def build(self, validated_data):
        return self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
```

But it's a drag not to have it on the base serializer, am I missing something?

Comment: Soufiane Mghanen gave you the right answer. ModelSeriazlier in REST framework will save the object before it is returned to you. If you want to have a serializer that doesn't do that, you can either inherit from Serializer and define your own object creation or inherit from ModelSerializer and override object creation. You don't need to do your own serialization or deserialization, since that is handled by to_representation() and to_internal_value(), but you do need to do your own object creation. Not sure what other answer you expect.

Comment: I don't know how much clearer I can be!  I want to know if this is functionality is supported in rest_framework out of the box.  If it's not, the right answer is "no, this feature doesn't exist in rest framework".

Comment: What feature? Can you make a serializer that will not persist instances? Yes, you can and we have explained how to do it. The default behavior is to save instances and we have explained that as well. What information are you missing?

Comment: The feature analogous to `Model(**data)` and `Factory.build`, i.e. to create a model instance without actually saving it.  I'm aware that the default behaviour is to save (as mentioned in the question), and I'm also aware of how to write my own code to make a serializer which does not save (this is also mentioned in the question).  So the answers below do not "explain" anything new to me.  The information that is missing is whether this is possible in rest framework without defining a custom method.  Is that clear enough for you?

Comment: I know that doesn't help but I've actually sent a patch that would've fixed your problem (and others). It was rejected because author didn't want to "increase API surface area"

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/3802/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L811-L846 (comments omitted):

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    raise_errors_on_nested_writes('create', self, validated_data)

    ModelClass = self.Meta.model

    info = model_meta.get_field_info(ModelClass)
    many_to_many = {}
    for field_name, relation_info in info.relations.items():
        if relation_info.to_many and (field_name in validated_data):
            many_to_many[field_name] = validated_data.pop(field_name)

    try:
        instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

The serializer `create()` method is a fairly thin wrapper around the model's `create()` method.

The bad news is that you're right, there's no memory-only serializer shortcut for:

```
class PotatoSerializer:
    ...
    def build(self, validated_data):
        return self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
```

The good news is that you can cut out the middle man and call the model directly:

```
Potato(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Default `Serializer` do save to the database. However, if you want to test against the validation, a simple call to `is_valid` will do and avoid saving to the database.

I'm mostly guessing as your question isn't very clear regarding your goal.

Comment: The goal is to create an instance of the model from the serializer, which exists in memory but doesn't hit the db.  I don't want to test validation.  `is_valid` creates for you the `validated_data`, but that's just a mapping.  I wanted a model instance.

Comment: This is a really special edge case. Usually you'll override create/update as you pasted in your question. If that's for performance reasons note that you can use in memory database which is what Django does when testing with sqlite as DB backend.

Comment: I don't want to override create/update, because I want to use those aswell.  I need both options.  Yes it's for testing, and and the in memory db does not seem to be an option here because I'm using some features of postgres that seems unsupported in sqlite

Comment: If sqlite doesn't support your features, you can try H2. That has somewhat better compatibility.

Comment: H2 with Django, really?  I've never heard of anyone doing that, only Postgres, MySQL, sqlite, and oracle.  I don't think it's supported in Django.

Answer (score 0):

in your PotatoSerializer, you need to override the Create method.
something like this:

```
class PotatoSerializer:
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # and here you change the default behavior of the serializer
        return Potato(**validated_data)
            # instead of
            # return Potato.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: This is not helpful, it's the same as what's already shown in the last code block in the original question.  Except worse, because it shadows the usual behavior for creating and persisting an instance.